# Bias, variance, train and test/validation error + total error

Tags: machine-learning, bias-variance-tradeoff

I'm trying to make sense out of the following two plots:

[image: img]
Source: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/bias-variance-tradeoff-machine-learning-satya-mallick/

[image: img2]
Source: https://towardsdatascience.com/the-bias-variance-tradeoff-8818f41e39e9

I'd say I understand them on their own but don't understand how to merge their meaning, especially w.r.t. to the validation error/variance.
The training error is present in both plots, but what about the validation error and/or variance? Why isn't it?

Is there a difference between high bias <> underfitting and high variance <> overfitting?

By having an eye on:

[image: img3]
Source: https://medium.com/@mp32445/understanding-bias-variance-tradeoff-ca59a22e2a83

I also wonder how to understand this in regard to the above. How can you separate four cases when there is obviously a tradeoff between two features (bias and variance)?

Comment: Can you provide the source of those plots or more of the context? At first glance, my guess is that the first is the empirical version, i.e. what you would observe for a single sample, while the latter is the theoretical version, computed over distribution of the samples instead of a single data set.

Comment: Thanks, I added the sources. Will think about what you wrote!